# how to check any of the input value has data before insert to db using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Insertion is happening when html table row is empty.if any of the input field has value allow to insert otherwise dont insert blank row to database.Where i need to change my code?MY datas are inserting if table row of datas are null

php code

```
    for ($count = 0; $count < count($itemname); $count++) {
        $itemname_clean  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $itemname[$count]);
        $unit_clean      = (int) $unit[$count];
        $quantity_clean  = (int) $quantity[$count];
        $rate_clean      = $rate[$count];
        $totamount_clean = $totamount[$count];
        $checkvat_clean  = $checkvat[$count];
        if ($itemname_clean != '' || $unit_clean != '' || $quantity_clean != '' || $rate_clean != '' || $totamount_clean != '') {
            $query .= '
   //insert query goes here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post sample `$_POST` array where you are facing the issue of blank insertion in DB. On a side note: a lot can be done to improve your code from SQL injection perspectives. Read up on Prepared statements and try to implement them!

Comment: in this php code blank row is not adding but all fields are compalsory fields(six columns then only its adding to db. i need to change like if any of these 6 input has value just add the row

Comment: Why you are using for loop... are you inserting value on basis of item name count ..?

Comment: table have multiple rows.."Add row " button is there.Using add row button appending the table row..table have 5 columns..and these are not compalsory to enter.If user enter any of these columns then allow to insert to database.

Comment: Now am facing an issue like if i append table(sl no:2) and these second i leave it as blank row then also insertion is happening.This second row should not be add to database.I need help where i need to change my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to check if any one of the variables has a value, then insert. But if all of the variables are empty, don't insert.

You have a mistake in your if statement. You are checking `$totamount` which is an array so it is not empty, so the if statement always resulted in true. But inside, you are inserting `$totamount_clean` to the database which might be empty.

So change `$totamount` to `$totamount_clean` in your if statement.

```
if (!empty($itemname_clean) || !empty($unit_clean) || !empty($quantity_clean) || !empty($rate_clean) || !empty($totamount_clean)) {
```

Comment: already i tried using this condition that time error showing like "All Fields are Required".I dont want to show this error..If any of the one input has value then allow to save otherwise dont save it

Comment: if ($itemname_clean != '' && $unit_clean != '' && $quantity_clean != '' && $rate_clean != '' && $totamount != '') {    } using this condition blank rows are not adding but user must enter these all columns.If user enter only the itemname error showing "all the fields are required" and its not inserting.Here i need to allow to insert data becoz already user enter only item name

Comment: can u plz help me?

Comment: if user doesnt enter anything in these six fields also insertion is happening.how to stop insert if all fields are blank?

Comment: you have any idea?

Comment: sorry, that was my fault, I've fixed it to use !empty($variable)